# Extract the last path-segments of a URI or path using RegEx

Tags: regex, path, uri, extract

I am trying to extract the last section of the following string :

```
"/subscriptions/5522233222-d762-666e-555a-e6666666666/resourcegroups/rg-sql-Belguim-01/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/vm-sql-image-v3.3-pre-sysprep-Oct-2021-BG"
```

I want to capture:

```
"snapshots/vm-sql-image-v3.3-pre-sysprep-Oct-2021-BG"
```

I tried below with no luck:

```
(\w*?\/\w*?)$
```

How to pull this off using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
[^\/]+\/[^\/]+$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/oXQ1sN/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\/]+                   any character except: '\/' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\/]+                   any character except: '\/' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: This is a generic path-matcher when `/` is the separator, matching the two last path segments.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your issues

`(\w*?/\w*?)$` is for simple or empty last 2 segments ([tested](https://regex101.com/r/CFPG8s/1)), e.g.

1. matched `hello/world/subscriptions123/snap_shots` capturing `subscriptions123/snap_shots`
2. matched `/1/2//` capturing the last 2 empty segments

OK was:

- capture-group
- `/` to match the last path-separator before end (`$`)
- `\w*?` intended to match the path-segment of any length

What to improve:

- `*?` is a bit too unrestricted, choose quantifier as `+` for at least one (instead `*` for any or `?` for zero or one)
- `\w` is for word-meta-character, does not match hyphens or dots (OK for `snapshot`, not for given last segment)

#### Quick-fixed

`(\w+/[\w\.-]+)$` ([tested](https://regex101.com/r/Gm7KHK/1))

- added dot `\.` and hyphen `-` to character-set containing `\w`

#### Simple but solid

`(snapshots/[^\/]+)$` ([tested](https://regex101.com/r/aMm5I2/2))

- fore-last path-segment assumed as fix constant `snapshots`
- `[^\/]` any character except (`^`) slash in last segment

Note: the slash doesn't need to be escaped `\/` like [Ryszard answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70979298/5730279)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed Explanation. Much appreciated. the "Snapshot" however is not fixed, it can be anything.

Comment: @MehdiPasha My answer was not intended to solve it, just to show your issues and how to fix. The generic regex of Ryszard can be applied to any path, because `[^/]` matches each segment between `/`. Anyway think both answers deserve a vote if helpful.